# Socket.io and Express getting an error "has no method socket"

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to test a basic Socket.io and Express set up (per the example on the socket.io website):

```
/Users/scottcorgan/Projects/sevenly/campaigns/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:659

        var socket = this.namespaces[i].socket(data.id, true);



 ^

TypeError: Object function extend(another) {
  var properties = Object.keys(another);
  var object = this;
  properties.forEach(function (property) {
    object[property] = another[property];
  });
  return object;
} has no method 'socket'
    at Manager.handleClient (/Users/scottcorgan/Projects/sevenly/campaigns/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:659:41)
    at Manager.handleUpgrade (/Users/scottcorgan/Projects/sevenly/campaigns/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:588:8)
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous> (/Users/scottcorgan/Projects/sevenly/campaigns/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:119:10)
    at HTTPServer.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (http.js:1390:14)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:334:27)
```

Appreciate any help I can get, please :)

Comment: Should be clear that whatever item you're getting from this.namespaces does not contain a method called socket. Paste more code if you want help tracking down the real problem.

Comment: Typically socket is not a method, it's an object, and you need to call `.emit()` or `.write()` on a given socket.

Comment: I am using the exact example from the socket.io website for Express:   [link](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) <~~ Socket.io "How To Use"

Comment: @scottcorgan: I can't find any reference to `this.namespaces[i].socket` in those examples?

Comment: I couldn't either. That's why I'm asking. I can't figure out why that error happens when I'm just using their example code ... I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

This problem stems from the fact that you or a library you use are adding functions to ***Object.prototype***.

Thus this code:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() {};
Object.prototype.bar = function() {};

var myObj = { x: 1 };

for (var i in myObj) {
   console.log(i)
}
```

will print: ***x, foo, bar*** (not necessarily in that order) and not just ***x*** as you expect.

In your case this happens in manager.js:

```
// initialize the socket for all namespaces
for (var i in this.namespaces) {
    var socket = this.namespaces[i].socket(data.id, true);

    // echo back connect packet and fire connection event
    if (i === '') {
        this.namespaces[i].handlePacket(data.id, { type: 'connect' });
    }
}
```

This code doesn't expect to encounter the declared: *extend* key, as you can see from the stack trace of the error:

```
TypeError: Object function extend(another) {
  var properties = Object.keys(another);
  var object = this;
  properties.forEach(function (property) {
    object[property] = another[property];
  });
  return object;
} has no method 'socket'
```

the program is actually tried to invoke ***socket()*** on the ***extend*** function.

See [Bob's rant here](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/07/01/javascript-frameworks/) about adding functions to **Object.prototype**.

As for the solution, you can either add a conditional statement inside manager.js like so:

```
// initialize the socket for all namespaces
for (var i in this.namespaces) {
    if ('extend' == i) continue;  // ADDED
    var socket = this.namespaces[i].socket(data.id, true);

    // echo back connect packet and fire connection event
    if (i === '') {
        this.namespaces[i].handlePacket(data.id, { type: 'connect' });
    }
}
```

or you can remove the ***Object.prototype.extend = function(...) {}*** declaration, which is my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.namespaces[i].socket(data.id, true);` does not exist. Do something like `console.log(typeof this.namespaces[i].socket(data.id, true));` You'll probably get an `undefined`

I bet one of the elements of your namespaces array is missing.

Comment: What do you mean by the namespace array?